Function lock on each startup in ubuntu 24.04 lts
I'm using asus laptop in that there is option to turn on and off the fn lock (Fn+esc).i'm dual booting the windows and the ubuntu 24.04 lts,the function lock is always turning on each startup,everytime i need to press the Fn+esc to tun off the fn lock.Is there any permanent solution to fix this issue?
